# Is it necessary to free a mutex created by xSemaphoreCreateMutex()?

Tags: esp32, freertos

FreeRTOS and ESP-IDF provide `xSemaphoreCreateMutex()` which allocates and initializes a mutex.  Their docs say:

> If a mutex is created using xSemaphoreCreateMutex() then the required
> memory is automatically dynamically allocated inside the
> xSemaphoreCreateMutex() function. (see
> http://www.freertos.org/a00111.html).

However, I can't find any info on whether it is necessary to free the memory created by the mutex.  This would be important if using C++ with a mutex member variable, like:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass::MyClass()
    {
        mAccessMutex = xSemaphoreCreateMutex();
    }
    
    MyClass::~MyClass()
    {
        // What to do here??
    }
    
    SemaphoreHandle_t mAccessMutex;
}
```

**REFERENCE**

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/freertos.html?highlight=xsemaphore#semaphore-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [FreeRTOS API reference](https://www.freertos.org/a00113.html#vSemaphoreDelete), the proper way to destroy/delete a mutex is `vSemaphoreDelete()`

> Deletes a semaphore, including mutex type semaphores and recursive
> semaphores.
>
> Do not delete a semaphore that has tasks blocked on it.

If you're using [heap_1](https://freertos.org/a00111.html#heap_1), deleting is not possible. Also, make sure that you fully understand the perils of dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems before using it. If `MyClass` is going to be created and destroyed in a regular/periodic basis, this may cause problems.

So yes, it's necessary to call `vSemaphoreDelete(mAccessMutex)` in `~MyClass()`. But it's probably best to make sure that `MyClass` instances never get destroyed. In my projects, I generally use one-time dynamic allocation during initialization and *forget* to implement a proper destructor (which is a bad habit that I need to fix).

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  I'm not using `new` but I suppose `~MyClass()` could get called if it went out of scope.  For completeness, I'd like the destructor to do the right thing.

Comment: @Danny , FreeRTOS has its own dedicated heap and memory allocation system. Functions like `xSemaphoreCreateMutex()` use this mechanism, which is very similar to `new`. So, even when you allocate `MyClass` instances on stack, the member mutex is still created in FreeRTOS heap and destruction of `MyClass` instances may cause memory fragmentation in FreeRTOS heap.

Comment: If you mind dynamic memory allocation, you can use `xSemaphoreCreateMutexStatic` and add the buffer in your class.

Comment: @Tagli I would appreciate a link to <<perils of dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems>>.